# Cookies across subdomains and hosts

Tags: php, django, apache, iis, cookies

In the application I'm writing using a combination of development environments and languages, I have need of accessing a cookie from two different subdomains, each on a separate host.

The cookie is being set on `www.mydomain.com` using the PHP code that follows, and I'm attempting to access it from `distant.mydomain.com` on a separate host.

```
setcookie('token', base64_encode(serialize($token)), time()+10800, '/', '.mydomain.com');
```

I'm trying to access the cookie from `distant.mydomain.com` using the following code:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['token'])) { /* do stuff */ }
```

**The problem: `distant.mydomain.com` is not finding the cookie.**  The `if` statement just mentioned returns false, even though the cookie exists.

I have verified that the cookie that is set is for `mydomain.com` (by checking my Firefox cookies).  I can't think of any reason this wouldn't be working.

Using the same `setcookie` code, I have an old application running exclusively on the `www.mydomain.com` host, and that application is able to access the cookie across domains.  This makes me suspect that the problem has to do with separate hosts.

Just in case any of the following information is pertinent:
- `www.mydomain.com` is IIS 6.0
- `distant.mydomain.com` is Apache 2.2.9
- Both servers use PHP 5.2.x
- Both servers are operating on Windows Server 2003

If there is any further information I can provide in order to better describe the problem, please let me know!

Comment: Sorry about that; I still haven't figured out why the second half of my post didn't make it through when I hit submit.

Comment: there's no question though still :)

Comment: Curses!  You know how the second time you have to write a post/e-mail/whatever, it's never as good as the first time?  *goes off to edit*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone reading this question the code and information contained in the original post are exactly correct and work fine.

The problem is when you introduce other technology.  For instance, **I have since learned that sending PHP code through a Python module, one that allows Django to serve PHP files/content, changes a great deal about what is accessible to the script and what is not.**

This was eventually discovered following the advice of [Marc Novakowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27020/marc-novakowski), who suggested sending `$_COOKIE` to the log in order to find out what was there.

I also checked out `$_SERVER` and `$_GET`.  It was the emptiness of `$_GET` that tipped me off that the setup I am attempting to use is not as straightforward as I had thought.  It was that mistaken understanding that led to not including the information about Django in the original post.

Apologies *and* thanks to all who responded to this question!

Answer (score 4):

Cookies set in domain

`'.aaa.sub.domain.com'`

will collide with identically named cookies set in domain

`'.sub.domain.com'`

and `'.some.stupidly.obscure.multi.sub.domain.com'`

That means (and this took some time to wade thru) if you're going to use the same-named cookie across multiple domains, you must set it once (and once only) in the main/base domain, in this case '.domain.com'; otherwise, the resulting cookie will be indeterminantly and randomly returned arrived at, sometimes the cookie 'jasper' set in .a.sub.domain.com, sometimes the cookie 'jasper' set in .sub.domain.com, sometimes the cookie 'jasper' set in .b.c.d.domain.com, sometimes the cookie 'jasper' set in '.sub.domain.com' and sometimes the cookie 'jasper' set in '.domain.com'

Answer (score 3):

Does one of the subdomains use an underscore ? IE has problems accepting cookies from subdomain's that dont follow the URI RFC.

This is asumming 'distant' is a placeholder and not the actual subdomain name and of course that you use IE. Although more browsers could very well be effected by as, Fireworks doesn't though.

Comment: The actual domain has a hyphen but all other characters are alpha.  The subdomains in question are exclusively alpha.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try installing [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and see what headers are a) being sent to Firefox to begin with (to set the cookie) and b) which headers are being sent from Firefox to the second server.  At least that way you can narrow down where the problem is (browser or server).

Comment: Useful tool!  I took a look, though, and the headers for requesting distant.mydomain.com and local.mydomain.com (the application that *can* read the cookie) were identical, save for the actual hostname.

Comment: If the browser's sending the cookie then it must be a server problem.  Maybe try logging or printing all the headers that the server sees coming in from the client, and try dumping everything in $_COOKIE to the log

Answer (score -3):

From php.net about the [setCookie](https://www.php.net/setcookie)-function:

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain . If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain . The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

> The domain that the cookie is available. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com then you'd set it to '.example.com'. The . is not required but makes it compatible with more browsers. Setting it to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will make the cookie only available in the www subdomain. Refer to tail matching in the » spec for details.

Basically: Your 4. and 5. parameter needs to be checked: Well, your path seems to be fine, but the domain needs to be changed:

Today you block the cookie to all others than domain A, but you want it to be awailable to both domain A and B. This is a bit tricky, but can be solved. Get inspiration on [15seconds](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm) ;-)

Comment: I may be interpreting your response incorrectly, but based on the http://php.net/setcookie documentation, my path and domain should be correct as given in my original question.  If they should be corrected, please provide an example of what the setcookie() function call should look like.

Comment: It seems i migth have misunderstand. When you told me you use two different servers, I automatically thought about two different hosts. But if the cookie only have to be visible at _one_ host, then your code seems correct. :-/