# Sharing user accounts between multiple sites

Tags: php, authentication

Here's a scenario:

You log into GMail at mail.google.com and then you go to docs.google.com and you are automatically logged in there too.

Is it possible to share user accounts between sites like that with PHP and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save session to a database instead of a file then have both sites look to that DB for session variables.

check this out
http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can.  Check out the answer to this post:

[Cookies across subdomains and hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376403/cookies-across-subdomains-and-hosts)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be to do just what GMAIL and THIS site do and use some type of open ID.
Or, you can just learn how they implement it and re-invent the wheel or create another open ID service.